# Can I perform mathematical operations on comma-separated numbers?

Tags: pandas, number-formatting, streamlit

I have this column in a streamlit dataframe, which is able to sort numeric values. I also want to add commas to the values so that it's more readable. However, when I do this it converts the column values to string format and so the column isn't able to sort the values properly. Is there any way I can keep the commas in the numbers while being able to sort them in streamlit as well?

Comment: Numbers don't contain thousand separators. They're just for the UI to make it easier for the user to read. They can't be stored in a number, because they don't exist in numbers. If you add them, it becomes a user-friendly string representation. Store it as a number so that you can do math with it, and add the thousand separators for display to the user when doing output to the screen/printer.

Comment: You can do this. But it requires extending a datatype in pandas. Its alitle overboard. I wish pandas could make it easier by providing more articles on this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, but since I'm displaying the numbers in a streamlit dataframe, there is an interactive sorting feature for each column which does not work if the numbers have commas in them. So is there a way I can do that while keeping the commas?